# Remove columns from query that aren't within the last six months?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I only want to see the last 6 month of data, not all columns. So right now that would be (Jul '19 - Dec '19). But next month when the table runs I would want to see (Aug '19 - Jan '20). I could just hide the columns in excel, but the goal is to make this as automated as possible, so I would like to only show the past 6 months of columns.

Here is my query (Postgres):

```
select 
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-01-31') as "Jan '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-02-28') as "Feb '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-03-31') as "Mar '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-04-30') as "Apr '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-05-31') as "May '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-06-30') as "Jun '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-07-31') as "Jul '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-08-31') as "Aug '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-09-30') as "Sep '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-10-31') as "Oct '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-11-30') as "Nov '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2019-12-31') as "Dec '19",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-01-31') as "Jan '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-02-28') as "Feb '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-03-31') as "Mar '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-04-30') as "Apr '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-05-31') as "May '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-06-30') as "Jun '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-07-31') as "Jul '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-08-31') as "Aug '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-09-30') as "Sep '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-10-31') as "Oct '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-11-30') as "Nov '20",
  min(rank_score) filter (where snapshot_date = '2020-12-31') as "Dec '20"
from power_rank.kpi_totals
where 
  KPI_code = 'Total'
  and territory_id = '0019'
group by 
  territory_id,
  kpi_code
``
```

Comment: It is easy to get the last six months.  It is hard to give them dynamic names based on the month.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you also provide a few sample data? `INSERT INTO` statements would be great:)

Comment: instead of separate rows, why don't you get two columns, 1 for month & 1 for rank_score?

Comment: @HaleemurAli For presentation purposes, trying to keep the data horizontal

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but the last day of February this year is 2020-02-29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way through SQL to dynamically assign the names of the columns, but I don't think you need to.  Name them generically in a way that makes sense (current - 1, current -2, etc) and then let Excel handle the actual column names.

Using just the table, this is one way to do what you seek:

```
select
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where k.snapshot_date >= current_date - interval '3 months' and k.snapshot_date < current_date - interval '2 months') as m_3,
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where k.snapshot_date >= current_date - interval '2 months' and k.snapshot_date < current_date - interval '1 month') as m_2,
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where k.snapshot_date >= current_date - interval '1 month' and k.snapshot_date < current_date) as m_1
from
  power_rank.kpi_totals k
where 
  k.KPI_code = 'Total' and
  k.territory_id = '0019' and
  k.snapshot_date between current_date - interval '3 months' and current_date
group by 
  k.territory_id, k. kpi_code
```

However, if you have control of your database, I recommend another way, which is to create a table that lists months and join on that table.  We have one we use just for queries like this, and it's tremendously valuable -- look at the query above and compare it to the one below that uses the table, and you will see for maintainability (and hopefully performance as well) it should do better.

Here is the table -- the methodology is that id = 0 always refers to the current month.  This is great because you can use the id in your queries to define your dynamic time frame.

[image]

And then the "easy" version is as follows:

```
select
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where a.id = -3) as m_3,
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where a.id = -2) as m_2,
  min (k.rank_score) filter (where a.id = -1) as m_1
from
  power_rank.kpi_totals k
  join util.all_months a on k.snapshot_date = a.month_end
where 
  k.KPI_code = 'Total' and
  k.territory_id = '0019' and
  a.id between -3 and -1
group by 
  k.territory_id, k.kpi_code
```